# Symfony 2 without CSS in FF and images in IE on server

Tags: deployment, symfony

I deployed my site to a OVH server with filezilla following the steps in this tutorial http://pilvee.com/blog/deploiement-symfony2/

After deployment I find that my site works fine but without CSS content in FF and Chrome, so when I check in firebug I find all CSS styles are loaded correctly but empty without content,also JS file are loaded with content and all images too.In IE I have the style that works fine but no image is loaded ??I work on Ubuntu and I use a Virtual Machine to use IE...

I published my asset with assets:install web,I almost did everything, I cleared the cache and I changed the access rights of all files, I specify for files => 705, the CSS and JS => 604,finally I put everything to 777 but still no change ...

That get me crazy really,i dont know what i do to get my website work,i thinked about rebuild my website again,I liked symfony 2 before but now I hate it...

An idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using assetic to manage your assets ?

```
$ app/console assetic:dump
```

Comment: I don't,but I guess   assets:install web is sufficient and what the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$ php app/check.php
```

can tell you more about your host configuration.

Comment: I guess i never change check.php,and please what you mean with my host configuration,do u mean  app/config.yml?